# Rails 3 Page Titles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have static Titles in my code for different pages.

How would i go about this, it keeps using the app name in the title.

I have tried

1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site under construction</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @page.title %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_page_path(@page) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', pages_path %>
</body>

</html>
```

That did not work

I have tried [rails page titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841323/rails-page-titles)

not working is there something i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is the contents of your view. The default rails project creates a layout that has the application name in the title element. Therefore, you are likely to have something not dissimilar to the following being sent to the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample application</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "…" SYSTEM "…">
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta …/>
          <title>Site Under Construction</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          …
        </body>
      </html>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The file you need to edit should be app/views/layouts/application.html.erb