# Rails - Setting title in layout from instance variable (controller or view?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, instance-variables

Let's say I have something like this in my application layout:

```
<title> <%= @page_title | MyPage </title>
```

I am wondering where is it better to set that instance variable. In the **controller** action, or in the **view**? Does it matter at all? I am asking in both performance and closest MVC way of doing it.

Comment: I remember using this answer a while ago, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3841549/590177 maybe it can be of use to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails encourages the use [`content_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method) in your views to pass this kind of content around. Others may have a better sense of how efficient this approach is, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recomend you to use [meta-tags gem](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags). You can easily set title `set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login'` and other SEO options like meta and etc.